# imagepicker won't let me run my app on android, on IOS it works fine

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run my app in ios simulation everything works fine, but on android I have an error I think with image picker and gradle here is the error :
I tried the mutlidex solution but it does not seem to work.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':image_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to 
try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin image_picker...
> Configure project :
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'
Consider disabling R8 by removing 'android.enableR8=true' from your gradle.properties before 
publishing your app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'imagepicker'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with 
an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

Exception: The plugin image_picker could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Comment: did you add permission on your androidmanifest.xml?

Comment: not really, how to?

Comment: it's in the documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: hey man thanks, I found the solution, I was following a tutorial and the tutor was using a very old version of imagepicker and I didn't notice.